# Bash provide options and pass variable on choice to be used later

Tags: bash

Trying to give an option to users of an installer to chose either "Development" or "Stable". By default the installer does "git checkout 1.1.0", but I'm turning 1.1.0 into $GIT_VERSION and trying to make a clean way to set that in the beginning.

Trying to set `$GIT_VERSION` to `master` or `1.1.0` with option of 1,2, or 3 (3 being quit). I've got a rough start of what I'm trying to do...

```
PS3='Do you want to install Lastest Stable or Latest Development: '
options=("Stable" "Development" "Quit")
select $GIT_VERSION in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $GIT_VERSION in
        "Stable")
            $GIT_VERSION=1.1.0 
            echo "Installing 1.1.0..."
            ;;
        "Development")
            $GIT_VERSION=master
            echo "Installing latest development version..."
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

option to be used as such `git checkout $GIT_VERSION` later down the line after dependencies installed and configured within the same script.

This is possibly a better solution...

```
PS3="<b>Latest Stable</b> recommended for production servers
<b>Development Snapshot</b> intended for testing purposes

What version to you wish to install: "

select option in Latest\ Stable Development\ Snapshot Quit
do
    case $option in
        Latest\ Stable) 
            $GIT_VERSION=1.1.0
            echo "Install set to Latest Stable...";;
        Development\ Snapshot) 
            $GIT_VERSION=master
            echo "Install set to Development Snapshot...";;
        Quit)
            exit;
     esac
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bold=`tput bold`
normal=`tput sgr0`
PS3="
${bold}Latest Stable${normal} recommended for production servers
${bold}Development Snapshot${normal} intended for testing purposes

What version do you want to install: "
echo -e "\r\n"
select option in "Latest Stable" "Development Snapshot" "Quit"
do
  case $option in
    "Latest Stable") 
      GIT_VERSION=1.1.0
      echo "Install set to Latest Stable..."
      break;;
    "Development Snapshot") 
      GIT_VERSION=master
      echo "Install set to Development Snapshot..."
      break;;
    "Quit")
      exit;
    esac
done
```

use `$GIT_VERSION` to get version value within script when cloning branch

Answer (score 2):

Don't<sup>*</sup> use `$` on the LHS of an assignment:

```
$GIT_VERSION=1.1.0
```

```
GIT_VERSION=1.1.0
```

Also, 'development' only has 3 e's in it, not 4.

---

#### Using `select`

After re-reading about `select` in the [GNU Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs),
I think this should work more or less sanely:

```
STABLE_VERSION=1.1.0
GIT_VERSION=$STABLE_VERSION
PS3='Do you want to install Latest Stable or Latest Development: '
options=("Stable" "Development" "Quit")
select release in "${options[@]}"
do
    case "$release" in
        "Stable")
            GIT_VERSION=$STABLE_VERSION 
            echo "Installing stable version $STABLE_VERSION..."
            ;;
        "Development")
            GIT_VERSION=master
            echo "Installing latest development version..."
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

This separates the variable controlling the `select` from the variable controlling the installation.  It also avoids repeating 1.1.0, so you can change to 1.1.1 or 1.2.0 in one place — a variation on the DRY Principle: Don't Repeat Yourself.

---

<sup>*
It is possible to use `$` on the LHS, but you need to know what you are doing, and it is much more often an error than correct.  In current `bash` or `ksh` shells, it basically doesn't work (fails to find a command with an equals sign in the name).  If you found an archaic enough Bourne shell, I believe (but now cannot prove) that if `GIT_VERSION` contained a string such as `ABC_XYZ`, then `$GIT_VERSION=1.1.0` would assign `1.1.0` to the variable `ABC_XYZ`.  This is still not the intended behaviour, which is the main point to take home.  The rest is esoterica that you're better off not knowing.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the tip! updated question, still not too sure about where `"${options[@]}"` falls into this mix

Comment: In the `case`, you are not on the LHS of an assignment, and you do need to use `"$GIT_VERSION"` (or without the double quotes, at a pinch).  I remember trying `select` once, probably in the last decade of the previous millennium.  I decided it wasn't sufficient help to me so I've largely ignored it since.  I'm not sure what you're doing is the correct way to use `select`...I'll have to do some research (in the same place that you would: [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the GNU Bash Manual).

Comment: Re: your footnote, `GIT_VERSION=ABC_XYZ; $GIT_VERSION=1.1.0` would (most likely) produce the error "bash: ABC_XYZ=1.1.0: command not found". You need to use the command `declare "$GIT_VERSION=1.1.0"` to get the effect of indirect assignment.

Comment: @chepner: interesting; Bash (and `sh` as link to Bash) and `ksh` both behave as you say.  I've not tried it in a good long while, but I think an original Bourne shell would behave as I suggested.  Whatever the shell's behaviour, it is very seldom the desired behaviour.  I'll update the footnote though.